# MAMP Stored Procedure: Commands out of sync error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have searched a lot and spent hours on this, but most of the answers seem to be far more comple. I seem to have some basic misunderstanding of I don't know what aspect. I am using MySQL version 5.5.34 and am trying to build a stored procedure, but whenever I am calling it I get an error:

```
SELECT
            s.SCHEMA_NAME,
            s.DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
               FROM `information_schema`.SCHEMATA s
                GROUP BY BINARY s.SCHEMA_NAME
                ORDER BY BINARY `SCHEMA_NAME` ASC
MySQL said: Documentation

#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I first define the very basic procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get;
SET delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE get()
BEGIN
    SELECT 'hey' AS col;
END //

SET delimiter ;
```

and afterwards try to call it with

```
CALL get();
```

when the error occurs. At the moment I am trying this in the phpMyAdmin interface.

I would be very happy if you could point me into the right direction!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I was working with a not up to date version of MAMP on OS X which still seemed to use deprecated mysql instead of mysqli. This led to some problems with stored procedures as mentioned in my question.

However, updating to the current version of MAMP solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use $this->db->reconnect(); Before call stored proceedure

Comment: I am using the phpMyAdmin interface of the MAMP server on OS X. But reloading the interface's page (or restarting the server) before calling the stored procedure isn't helping, unfortunately.